# how to make two api requests using a response param and conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, if-statement, unirest

I'm trying to use this conditional so if the response does not contain a sectionid it will return the first response and if it does contain a sectionid it will return the second response.  The problem is, is that sectionid is in the response and I'm not sure how to define the conditional with the response before I make the request, the way I'm currently doing it the first response is returned no matter the circumstance of the request. any help would be much appreciated thanks.

```
 def show
  if "sectionId" != true 
    @events = Unirest.get("https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v2?eventid=#{params[:id]}&limit=1000&start=0&rows=1000&sectionStats=true", headers:{"Accept" => "application/json", "Authorization" => "Bearer*****"}).body
 else
   @events = Unirest.get("https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v2/sectionsummary?eventid=#{params[:id]}", headers:{"Accept" => "application/json", "Authorization" => "Bearer ******"}).body
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition will always be true because you are checking if the string value `"sectionId"` is different to the boolean value `true`. It's always different.

Shouldn't it be `params[:sectionId]` instead of `"sectionId"`? Look at the logs and check what params are entering into `show`. Alternatively, add `puts params.inspect` on the first line of show to directly output them on your console.

Comment: Will try this out thanks, my only question is when you do params[:sectionid] isn't that referring to a query param in the request not a body Param in the response?

Comment: I don't understand, you are trying to determine the response from the response? The response should depend on what's in the request. I think you maybe mean that the request has a JSON payload .. if so, yes, if the client sends it with the appropriate request header - `content-type: application/json`, Rails will automatically set params from that.

Comment: yes i think so thanks, I tried to add this code, but i'm not getting the result I want does this make sense? `@events = Unirest.get("https://api.stubhub.com/search/inventory/v2?eventid=#{params[:id]}&limit=1000&start=0&rows=1000&sectionStats=true", headers:{"Accept" => "application/json", "Authorization" => "Bearer ***"}).body`

      `@events.each do |listing|
       if listing[0]["sectionId"].present?
       render 'show.html.erb'`
      `else
        render 'index.html.erb'`
       `end`
     `end`
  ` end`

Comment: The condition looks better but you shouldn't be putting render inside the loop. First construct a string by looping, them use render to output it. Or better still, do that in your view template. I would start by making a separate class like `StubHub` and unit testing the data structure it receives, and whatever functions your template needs to render that.